# pdfjs not working on xampp server but works on node server

Tags: pdfjs-dist

I am trying to integrate pdfjs into my project and while development, when the root is in xampp server I am getting error.

But when I run on node server (live-server), I don't get any error

**code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <base href="/">
    <style>
        body{
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- 
        - not working and getting erros as shown below
        - the xampp path is localhost/silicon-craft-2/slide
     -->
    <!-- <iframe src="http://localhost/silicon-craft-2/slide/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=http://localhost/silicon-craft-2/slide/assets/presentation.pdf" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe> -->
    
    <!-- 
        - below code is executed with node package live server with root as /
     -->


    <iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/presentation.pdf" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>


</body>

</html>
```

I understand the error is on the path to the root. It might work once its moved to production. But for development how to override this error.

**Error Image**

[image]